# Возврат на View, с которого был вызван метод другого контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В дефолтном файле `_Layout.cshtml`, который является главным слоем, есть 2 кнопки, которые переключают язык сайта:

```
<div class="language-flags">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "en" }, null)">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/icons/en_flag.png")" title="English"/>
    </a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "ru" }, null)">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/icons/ru_flag.png")" title="Русский"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Есть `LanguageController.cs`:

```
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Change(string LanguageAbbrevation)
    {
        if (LanguageAbbrevation != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
        }
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return View(); // В этом и проблема
    }
}
```

Так же есть пустая вьюшка `Change`, чтобы не было ошибок.

Дело в том, что эти кнопки отображаются на каждой странице сайта и после нажатия, пользователя отправляет на страницу `Change`. Пользователя никуда отправлять не надо, только обновить текущую View. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно передавать в action дополнительным параметром URL, на который необходимо сделать возврат:

```
public ActionResult Change(string LanguageAbbrevation, string ReturnUrl)
{
    // здесь все то же самое

    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
}
```

В `_Layout` указываем значение этого дополнительного параметра как `Request.Url.PathAndQuery`:

```
<div class="language-flags">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "en", ReturnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/icons/en_flag.png")" title="English" />
    </a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "ru", ReturnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/icons/ru_flag.png")" title="Русский" />
    </a>
</div>
```